# File permissions and applications

Tags: kernel, application-development

How does ubuntu protect against executable files which become executable through another installed app changing the permissions? I mean it is possible to check applications do not change file permissions by checking their code but is there any other way of doing that?

Comment: When you say "How does ubuntu protect" do you mean whether it is possible or is not? Please, explain a bit more what you want to know/understand and why.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think permissions can propagate, imagine in a pipe, you still need to add "sudo" for each command in order to lift the permission constraint, not only once.

Comment: No you can actually change file permissions without sudo.

Comment: chmod command need permission too.